# Is there a way in Acumatica's BQL to perform select distinct query on a single field?

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to use BQL to get a recordset from SOLine (joined to BCSyncDetails table/DAC) of just the distinct orderNbr values.  I've tried using the PXSelectJoinGroupBy method:

```
var solines = PXSelectJoinGroupBy<SOLine, 
              InnerJoin<BCSyncDetail, 
                  On<SOLine.noteID, Equal<BCSyncDetail.localID>>>,
              Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLine.orderNbr, Max<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base);
```

It's essentially this SQL query:

```
    SELECT  
    DISTINCT OrderNbr
    FROM     SOLine 
             INNER JOIN BCSyncDetail
                 ON SOLine.NoteID = BCSyncDetail.LocalID
                 AND SOLine.CompanyID = BCSyncDetail.CompanyID
    ORDER
    BY       OrderNbr
```

Am I not writing this correctly?  Can't find a good example anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to rewrite your query like this

> var solines = PXSelectJoinGroupBy<SOLine,
> InnerJoin<BCSyncDetail,
> On<SOLine.noteID, Equal<BCSyncDetail.localID>>>,
> Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLine.orderNbr, Max<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base).RowCast<SOLine>().ToList();

so you can use a LINQ query on the local object.  Faster, easier, more powerful once you have it in the enumerable.  The RowCast command above is the key, made my life easier.

> var distinctSOLines= solines.Select(x=>x.OrderNbr).Distinct();

Comment: Friendly recommendation for F-BQL. It's much easier to read and write 